# Remove last 4 characters of a file in a folder with a batch file

Tags: batch-file

this should be pretty simple, i just want a bat file that when placed in a folder will rename all files within the folder and delete the final 4 characters, but not the extension

ex.

```
img (1).jpg
```

becomes

```
img.jpg
```

ive tried

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if not exist %1 goto :eof
for /f %%A in ('find /V /C "" ^<%1') do set lines=%%A
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=[]" %%A in ('find /V /N "" ^<%1') do (
if %%A LSS %lines% (
echo %%B
) else (
set rec=%%B
echo !rec:~0,-4!
)
)
```

but it doesnt work. theres no error, it runs, it just doesnt do anything

Comment: Please show your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: `echo !rec:~0,-4!%%~xB`

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code as follows:

1/ switched to a test directory (PUSHD testdirectoryname) and back (POPD)
2/ changed the `%1` to a fixed filename
3/ Inserted some debug lines

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following setting for the source directory includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

PUSHD  "%sourcedir%"

if not exist q71992787.txt goto :eof
TYPE "%sourcedir%\q71992787.txt"
for /f %%A in ('find /V /C "" ^<q71992787.txt') do set lines=%%A
SET li
find /V /N "" <q71992787.txt
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=[]" %%A in ('find /V /N "" ^<q71992787.txt') do (
 if %%A LSS %lines% (
  echo %%B
 ) else (
  set rec=%%B
  echo !rec:~0,-4!
 )
)

POPD

GOTO :EOF
```

The result, other than the debug lines, was a list of the filenames in the file
`q71992787.txt`, other than the very last filename, which was shortened by 4 characters.

This differs from your result "it just doesnt do anything". This is why I mention it.

So - to your solution:

I can see no reason for calculating the number of lines in the file. If there are 10 lines for example, then reading the same file again with 'find /v /n` will still find 10 lines.

The `if %%A LSS %lines%` will `echo %%B` (the filename) if `%%A` (the line number) is **LESS** (`LSS`) than 10; that is, from 1 to 9 - just show the filename.

The `else` clause will only be processed if `%%A` is 10 or greater, so only on the last line.

I'm sure this wasn't what you intended to do.

I'd advise you to use `set "var1=value"` for setting **STRING** values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Quotes are not needed for setting arithmetic values `(`set /a`)

Where you alter your filename, setting `rec` to `%%B` means the *entire* filename, `%%B`. You don't show us a sample from the file `%1`, so I'll presume it's `img (1).jpg` as your narrative mentions. `rec` will thus become `img (1).jpg` and then be shortened to `img (1)` by removing the last 4 characters of the string.

Since you seem to want to remove the last 4 characters of the *name* part and leave the extension, then you need to read the documentation for `for` (**for /?** from the prompt) which will tell you

```
set "rec=%%~nB"
```

will assign just the *name* part and you could then

```
set "rec=!rec:~0,-4!%%~xB"

echo !rec:~0,-4!%%~xB
```

to set or show the manipulated name.

As to why you get no result at all; This could be because the file encoding of `%1` is unicode or is *nix format (, not  line endings)

And I do hope you're not using a *nix emulator like `cygwin` where `find` becomes a file-locator, not a string-analyser.

Answer (score 0):

The file renaming task for all *.jpg and *.jpeg files in the current directory of which file name ends with a space and a single digit number in round brackets can be done with a batch file with following command lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "* (?).jpg" "* (?).jpeg" /A-D /B /ON 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R /C:" ([0123456789])\.jpe*g$"') do (
    set "FileName=%%~nI"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    ren "!FileName!%%~xI" "!FileName:~0,-4!%%~xI"
    endlocal
)
endlocal
```

That code works also for image file names containing one or more exclamation marks and one or more round brackets before the last four characters in file name to remove.

**Note:** The command **REN** outputs an error message if the current directory contains the two files `photo (1).jpg` and `photo (2).jpg` on renaming the second file to `photo.jpg` because of this is not possible after first file already renamed to `photo.jpg`. There cannot be two files with same name in same directory.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with using a separate command process started in background.

Answer (score -1):

Doing it in PowerShell would be much easier

```
 ls *.jpg |% { ren $_ -ne ($_.BaseName.Substring(0, $_.BaseName.Length - 4) + $_.Extension) -wi }
```

`-wi` or `-WhatIf` is the option for dry running. After checking that the new names are OK you can remove that option. Full command line without alias:

```
Get-ChildItem -File *.* | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -WhatIf -Path $_ `
    -NewName ($_.BaseName.Substring(0, $_.BaseName.Length - 4) + $_.Extension) }
```